# How can I store the headers of a CSV file in an array?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have looked around and it should be fairly simple , the code I found was like this:

```
$headers = import-csv $file |
  select-object -first 1 | foreach-object { $_.PSObject.Properties } |
  select-object -expandproperty Name
```

but did not work, checking teh $headers will show as empty or null , i have another array which I use to check by using write-host , and the other array works fine, but the one created with the code above does not at all.

I just want to store on $headers an array that has the headers of the csv file.

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "did not work" :)

Comment: sure, let me add details

Comment: Try `$headers = (Get-Content -Path $file | select -First 1) -split ","` or `$importedfile[0].PSObject.Properties.Name`.

Comment: what xyz said , was the answer, thanks a lot :)